# Adding data in an has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, has-many-through

My project consists of People, Events and Comments.

Users can post comments ( accounts are not necessary ) and can attend events.

I'm using a `has_many: through` association between the people and events but whatever I try, I can't add people to events.

I don't have a clue how I can select someone and add this person to the `event_people` table.

The models

```
class EventPeople < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :event
belongs_to :people
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :title, presence:true, length: {minimum: 3}
validates :date_from, presence:true
validates :date_to, presence:true
validates :time_from, presence:true
validates :time_to, presence:true
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
has_many :people, :through => :event_people
has_many :event_people
end

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
validates :name, presence: true
validates :email, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5}
validates :birthdate, presence: true
has_many :comments
has_many :events, :through => :event_people
has_many :event_people
end
```

show method from the eventcontroller

```
def show
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
end
```

the table

```
create_table "event_people", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "event_id"
t.integer  "people_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: How do you want to do it?  Does someone add themselves or does whoever creates the event add the people?

Comment: Anyone should be able to add any of the people who are registered in the database. It's probably quite easy to pull off but i have been staring at this for quite a while and i haven't figured out what i should do

Answer (score 0):

Delete the 
`has_many :event_people`
in your People and Event Class

and your migration should look like:

```
create_table "event_people" do |t|
  t.belongs_to  :event
  t.belongs_to  :people
  t.timestamps
end
```

Comment: if i make these adjustments, how should i select someone and add them to the list of people who will be attending this event?

Comment: `people.events.build` will add an event to an existing person and vice versa `events.people.build` adds a person to an event. Of course you have to identify people and event through some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add them individually as klausinho is suggesting, have a from for `EventPeople` where you'd add one person at a time.

Or the `has_many` association will give you the `people_ids=` method on events. So you can then use [collection check boxes](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes)

```
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes(:people_ids, People.order(:name), :id, :name)
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Or you could use a multiple select instead.